# Python BeautifulSoup - extract text and attribute values

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML:

```
<td class="course-section-type"><span class="text-capitalize">lecture (5)</span></td>
<td class="course-section-meeting">
   <table class="no-borders" width="100%">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td width="23%">MWF</td>
            <td width="55%">11:30 AM - 12:20 PM</td>
            <td width="22%"><span><a href="http://myurl.com" target="_blank">MGH</a> <span class="sr-only">building room</span> 389</span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</td>
<td class="course-section-sln">00000</td>
```

I'd like to extract the values of top-level "class" attributes and map them to a list of lower level text. For the above HTML, that would look something like:

```
data = {
    "course-section-type": ["lecture (5)"],
    "course-section-meeting": ["MWF", "11:30 AM - 12:20 PM", "MGH", "building room", "389"],
    "course-section-sln": ["00000"]
}
```

I know that I can extract all the text with `soup.findAll('td').text`, but I don't know how to traverse the html tree nor how to extract the value of a tag attribute. How would I go about doing this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do all the top level td tags class values contain _course-section-_ ? And how do you see the final structure when doing this for lots more source lines?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Turns out BeautifulSoup provides a keyword argument `findAll(text=True)` that finds all the text under a certain tag (using inorder traversal) and puts it in a list.

```
d = {}
for tag in line.findAll('td'):
    if tag.get("class") and "course" in tag.get("class")[0]:
        d[tag.get("class")[0]] = [text.strip() for text in tag.findAll(text=True)]
>>> d
{"course-section-type": ["lecture (5)"], 
"course-section-meeting": ["MWF", "11:30 AM - 12:20 PM", "MGH", "building room", 
"389"], "course-section-sln": ["00000"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution is extract everything in this pattern,

cause its table in table, so the schema has to be fixed, otherwise nexttime when it changes, everything breaks again

course-section-type is outer table first `<td>` text

course-section-meeting is inner table everything text

course-section-sln is outer table third `<td>` text

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I was looking for a more generalized solution. The actual html for this is ~4000 lines--I can't use a hardcoded pattern for all of it.

Comment: if you find a solution , do tell me, we were dealing with wiki dump before, the solution is no where close